# Launching applescript from javascript

Tags: javascript, applescript

Is it possible to launch an applescript file from javascript in a web browser?  Can someone provide me with a code sample if it is?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is this JavaScript file running? A [JS OSA](http://www.latenightsw.com/freeware/JavaScriptOSA/), or in a web browser?

Comment: I'm having a difficult time thinking of a legitimate use for this that -wouldn't- endanger the user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an applescript application which registers with the OS as the handler of specific URL protocols and schemes.

See the following link for details:

http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/index.html